# How to rotate text while creating PDF in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

I am placing text on pdf something like this using Zend_Pdf:

```
$page1->drawText( 'Hello World!', 100, 100 );
```

But now I want to rotate text to 90 degree on pdf. How is it possible ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:
$page->rotate(0, 0, M_PI/12);
$page->drawText('Hello world!', 100, 100);
See also: [Zend PDF tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2525)

Comment: Do you need to rotate back before continuing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rotate() which uses Radians to determine the amount to rotate.

For example:

```
    // Rotate at the X and Y coordinates 
    // and 90 Degrees Counter-Clockwise (which is 1.5708 Radians)
    $page->rotate(300, 300, 1.5708);
```

Use [this tool](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/degrees-to-radians.html) calculate the value from degrees. Whilst you can use the constants in PHP and divide (as the other answer suggests) I would not recommend that personally (as I find it much harder to work out what it equates to).

You do need to rotate back before continuing with the next lines (assuming you want them to be horizontal).