# Zend_pdf - rotate text half way the page 90* then print and continue (-90*)

Tags: magento, zend-pdf

I am editing a document using zend_pdf (magento invoice)

And I am trying to achive to print the address block in the left top quadrant of an A4 paper, 90 degrees rotated (for envelope window)

Using the hints found here: [How to rotate text while creating PDF in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363460/how-to-rotate-text-while-creating-pdf-in-zend-framework)

```
$page->rotate(0, 0, deg2rad(-90));
$page->drawText('Hello world!', 100, 100);
```

**My question is**: how do I rotate the setting back when I have printed the address box? (so I continue with 0 degrees rotation)

**Also**: does the rotation 0,0 mean that it rotates the paper itself? (using the top left corner as an anchor? (it seems I am also loosing the bearing on the paper when using this method)

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rotate back using

```
$page->rotate(0, 0, deg2rad(-90));
```